# NewUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder crashes the Gmail IOS app

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

On the current Gmail iPhone app, calling the `newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder` crashes the app. No errors get logged and those crashed calls never appear in the 'Executions' tab in the App Script console.

The same code runs fine on the Android Gmail app or in the browser.

## Code to reproduce

**index.gs**

```
function attachRecording() {

return CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
    .setUpdateDraftBodyAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftBodyAction()
      .addUpdateContent('<h1>hello</h1>', CardService.ContentType.IMMUTABLE_HTML)
      .setUpdateType(CardService.UpdateDraftBodyType.IN_PLACE_INSERT))
    .build();
}
```

**appsscript.json**

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute"
  ],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Vocal",
      "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/mic_black_48dp.png",
      "universalActions": [
        {
          "label": "Manage account",
          "openLink": "https://app.vocal.email"
        }
      ],
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "onWelcomeClick"
      },
      "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    "gmail": {
      "composeTrigger": {
        "selectActions": [
          {
            "text": "Record voice message",
            "runFunction": "attachRecording"
          }
        ],
        "draftAccess": "NONE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried the different methods of the function listed here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/update-draft-action-response-builder

Whether it's adding a subject or text/html in the body. it always crashes the app.

Comment: Hey @Nath did you ever figure this out?